# Starting Visual Studio 2010 Without .Net Framework 4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

How can i uninstall .net framework 4 from VS2010 and have it (VS) still working?

If you just uninstall .net 4, VS doesnt start and shows "Unknown Error".

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have compatibility problems with one automation tool, it works perfect is .net 4 did not present in system, but crashes if it does.
Simplest way to make it working is to remove .net 4 (we don't use it anyway).

Comment: you can have multiple versions of .NET installed side by side without a problem. Think of the number of apps using different versions

Comment: I know. But, i need fast solution, i do not need .net 4 by now and i know it would help.. so, i think it's good decision to just remove .net 4.

Comment: @odd: I don't agree. Find and Fix the real problem... See @paulmey's
 answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run VS2010 without .NET 4.0.

You can force an application to use a specific version of the runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cd9b2c(VS.80).aspx . You can use this for your automation tool.